# Check if Item in a DataGrid is already in view

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` where the `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<LogEntry>`. On a click on a `Button` the user can scroll to a specific LogEntry. Therefor I use the following code:

```
private void BringSelectedItemIntoView(LogEntry logEntry)
{
    if (logEntry != null)
    {
        ContentDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(logEntry);
    }
}
```

This just works fine. But what I don't like is: If the LogEntry already is in view then the `DataGrid` flickers shortly.

My question now is:

Is there a possibility to check on the `DataGrid` if the given LogEntry already is in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get index for first visible item and last visible item

then you can check if your item's index was within first and last or not.

```
var verticalScrollBar = GetScrollbar(DataGrid1, Orientation.Vertical);
var count = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
var firstRow = verticalScrollBar.Value;
var lastRow = firstRow + count - verticalScrollBar.Maximum;

// check if item index is between first and last should work
```

Get Scrollbar method

```
private static ScrollBar GetScrollbar(DependencyObject dep, Orientation orientation)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dep); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dep, i);
            var bar = child as ScrollBar;
            if (bar != null && bar.Orientation == orientation)
                return bar;
            else
            {
                ScrollBar scrollBar = GetScrollbar(child, orientation);
                if (scrollBar != null)
                    return scrollBar;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: With one small improvement it works fine. Instead of the name of the scrollbar you should check on the `Orientation` of the Scrollbar

Comment: ah ! yea we can do that, feel free to improve the ans :)

Comment: How do you add and compare logical value (DataGrid1.Items.Count) and visual units value (verticalScrollBar.Value) i wonder? I get scroll bar's value as 1135 while grid has only 32 items, so how could it solution work, or maybe i did something wrong?